# Angularjs $document[0].activeElement instead of $document.activeElement

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am writing a placeholder directive using angularjs.

On the click handler I want to check if the element and document.activeElement are the same.

I tried to use `$docuemnt.activeElement` for that but it was always `undefined`. But when I used `$document[0].activeElement` I am getting the currently active element.

Is `$document[0].activeElement` is the right way to access the currently active element? Or am  doing something wrong?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

No, `$document` is a wrapped version of `document`, it is wrapped using jQlite which is a tiny version of jQuery, so `$document` doesn't have any method called `activeElement` because `document` is inside `$document`, So you'll have to use

```
$document[0].activeElement
```

Or

```
document.activeElement
```

You could also create a global variable that is a wrapped version of activeElement like so.

```
var $activeElement = angular.element(document.activeElement);
$activeElement.attr('focused', 'yes'); // Example usage
```

Comment: So you are telling i am using it the right way?  Feels weird for me though.

Comment: If it feels weird then just use `document.activeElement`

Comment: @iConnor Why do we need to use $document[0] instead of just $document?

Answer (score 0):

Just as an additional note is you use the above answer with:

`$document[0].activeElement`

Then you are actually an array of active elements so you need to use:

`$document[0].activeElement[0]`

or

`angular.element($document[0].activeElement)[0]`